# Making a connection to Azure SQL database from the Azure Worker role

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-sql-database

My objective is to create a worker role which connect to a Azure SQL database. 
For that I added a new setting in my Worker role as

```
connection String : Server=tcp:xyz.database.windows.net;
Database=abc;User ID=Dbadmin;
Password=abcxyz;
Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;
```

But it gives the following error :

> the storage account credentials entered are invalid

Can anyone help what I am missing here?

Comment: Shouldn't it be Initial Catalog = [DB name] not Database=[DB Name]?

Comment: @DanRediske-MSFT- Even with the Initial Catalog, I see the same issue.

Comment: The error says "**storage account credentials**", but you are setting SQL connection, this is weird.Could you share more about how you config the connection?

Comment: Have you been able to login to the DB with those credentials in SSMS?

Comment: Yes. I got around this problem by simple adding the string in config file directly and not using the UI to add connection string. Thanks anyways :)